# Как составить запрос к MySQL, включающий JSON-параметр?

Tags: json, sql, mysql

Имеется поле в формате json (varchar(2000), к примеру). В данном объекте имеется необходимое значение. Как мне составить запрос, чтобы он включал также и этот параметр, закодированный в json строку и помещенный в одно из полей таблицы?

Comment: Жестяной вопрос :))) Три раза пречитал, прежде чем понял :)

Comment: Напиши свой вариант. Не знаю как проще написать!)

Comment: Насколько понял, 2 запроса минимум - в Mysql вряд ли есть функция JSON_(DE-)ENCODE.

Comment: Я переделываю логику. В базе данные храняться в json формате, а данных ну оч много. Порядка 2000 записей. Каждый раз выбирать все, а потом искать в этом просто накладно. Поменять не могу, так как на этом завязан код админки, а мне лишь верстку прикрутить просят)

Comment: Ну в принципе мб вам понятнее будет, что в mysql нет функций для разбора json, как и js-объектов, php-serialize'ов и прочего такого. 

Как вариант, добавьте в таблицу одно поле и один раз прогоните все 2000 записей (взял одну - распарсил json - обновил поле). Потом измените запрос добавления в базу, чтобы это поле тоже шло.

Пример. Добавляем поле MyParam1. Потом для всех записей в цикле обновляем это поле (`" SET MyParam1=\'{$json->Param1}\'"`). Потом находим функцию обновления и дописываем ей то же.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно поизвращаться. к примеру имеем json:

```
{
   "firstName": "Иван",
   "lastName": "Иванов",
   "address": {
       "streetAddress": "Московское ш., 101, кв.101",
       "city": "Ленинград",
       "postalCode": 101101
   },
   "phoneNumbers": [
       "812 123-1234",
       "916 123-4567"
   ]
}
```

тогда

```
select substr(substring_index(substr(TEXT,locate('"lastName": "',TEXT)),'",',1),14) as txt from table having txt = 'Иванов'
```

где TEXT поле с json, а 14 длина выражения <"lastName": ">

Comment: Думаю лучшего варианта не придумать. Вопрос задал давно и ответ уже придумал сам, но он похож на Ваш, так что Вам зачет!)